# How multiprocessing is done in Single Core Systems?

Tags: operating-systems

Can we do multiprocessing on single core system ? I thought that single core means that ONLY one process/thread can execute at any time. For multiple processes , there can be concurrent execution to appear as they are executing Simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

The operating system (or the thread scheduler) switches from one thread to another at more or less regular intervals, making it look as if these threads were running simultaneously.